# how to show plugin in network admin section in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

I have installed some plugins in wordpress multisite and these are showing under admin panel and also child site's dashboard

But unfortunately not showing in Network Admin section. But I need to show those there.

Please help how to do so.

Comment: are the plugins multisite compatible? if you tell us what plugins you want to use we maybe can help you.

Comment: I am using http://wpbookingcalendar.com/demo/ plugin 

And also I have developed few plugins and using those.